# How Do I Create a Calculator To Add User Inputs From Same EditText?

Tags: android

I want to create a calculator only to add the user digit inputs given in same edittext and show in second edittext. Here is an example.

52 is entered by user in a EditText.

i want to perform addition in these number and show the result in second edittext.

answer should be 5+2=7.

i don't now what to perform

so  i am performing this task.

```
            int ans = a+b;    

            final int[] oil={ans};

            final String str = String.valueOf(R.id.editText1);

            final int y = Integer.parseInt(str);

            final int z = oil[y];


            et2.setText(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are expecting i think

```
 String val=et1.getText().toString();
    char[] valarry =val.toCharArray();
int result= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(valarry[0]))+Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(valarry[1]));
et2.setText(result);
```